# Color words in powershell script format-table output

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to color only certain words (not complete lines) for a powershell output using format-table.  For example, this script scans a folder recursively for a string and then output the result with format-table.

```
dir -r -i *.* | Select-String $args[0] |
format-table -Property @{label="Line #"; Expression={$_.LineNumber}; width=6},
Path, Line -wrap
```

It would be nice to be able to format the word we are searching for with a specific color, so that you can see exactly where it was found on the line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could pipe the table into `Out-String`, then write the string in parts using `Write-Host` with the `-NoNewLine` switch.

Something like this:

```
filter ColorWord {
    param(
        [string] $word,
        [string] $color
    )
    $line = $_
    $index = $line.IndexOf($word, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    while($index -ge 0){
        Write-Host $line.Substring(0,$index) -NoNewline
        Write-Host $line.Substring($index, $word.Length) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color
        $used = $word.Length + $index
        $remain = $line.Length - $used
        $line = $line.Substring($used, $remain)
        $index = $line.IndexOf($word, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    }
    Write-Host $line
}

Get-Process| Format-Table| Out-String| ColorWord -word 1 -color magenta
```

Comment: Works great!  Modified this line:

    $index = $line.IndexOf($word)

to

    $index = $line.IndexOf($word, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

Comment: Good point on the ignore case. I've updated the answer with the modification.

Answer (score 6):

I like [Rynant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362097/color-words-in-powershell-script-format-table-output/7362596#7362596)'s approach. Here is an alternate implementation, using [`-split`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347708.aspx) instead of [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx):

```
filter ColorWord( [string]$word, [ConsoleColor]$color ) {
    $later = $false
    $_ -split [regex]::Escape( $word ) | foreach {
      if( $later ) { Write-Host "$word" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color }
      else { $later = $true }
      Write-Host $_ -NoNewline
    }
    Write-Host
}
```

Split includes empty strings if the line starts or ends with the given word, hence the extra "if not first" logic.

---

**Edit:** Following Rynant's comment, here's another implementation that supports both simple and regex patterns:

```
filter ColorPattern( [string]$Pattern, [ConsoleColor]$Color, [switch]$SimpleMatch ) {
  if( $SimpleMatch ) { $Pattern = [regex]::Escape( $Pattern ) }
  
  $split = $_ -split $Pattern
  $found = [regex]::Matches( $_, $Pattern, 'IgnoreCase' )
  for( $i = 0; $i -lt $split.Count; ++$i ) {
    Write-Host $split[$i] -NoNewline
    Write-Host $found[$i] -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $Color
  }
  
  Write-Host
}
```

The output from the following examples shows the difference:

> `PS> '\d00\d!' | ColorPattern '\d' 'Magenta' -Simple`
> `\d00\d!`
>
> `PS> '\d00\d!' | ColorPattern '\d' 'Magenta'`
> `\d00\d!`

Comment: Just beware that you need to escape regex characters. E.g. `'Ke$ha - Tik Tok.mp3'| ColorWords 'ke\$ha' red`. Alternatively, `$_ -split [regex]::Escape($word)` could be used in the filter. Unless you want to match with regex, which could be nice.

Comment: @Rynant Thanks for pointing that out! Updated with new version.

Answer (score 4):

I love answer @Ryant gave.  I have a modified version here that can be used for colouring multiple words in an output by passing in arrays or words and colours. The trick is that you have to split the input text into lines based on the newline separator.

```
filter ColorWord2 {
param(
    [string[]] $word,
    [string[]] $color
)
$all = $_
$lines = ($_ -split '\r\n')

$lines | % {
    $line = $_      
    $x = -1

    $word | % {
        $x++
        $item = $_      

        $index = $line.IndexOf($item, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)                            
            while($index -ge 0){
                Write-Host $line.Substring(0,$index) -NoNewline                 
                Write-Host $line.Substring($index, $item.Length) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color[$x]
                $used =$item.Length + $index
                $remain = $line.Length - $used
                $line =$line.Substring($used, $remain)
                $index = $line.IndexOf($item, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            }
        }

    Write-Host $line
} }
```

and would be executed as follows

```
Get-Service | Format-Table| Out-String| ColorWord2 -word 'Running','Stopped' -color 'Green','Red'
```

Comment: I love this answer, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Cheers. I actually use a variation on this now. Rather than passing in two arrays, I just pass in a hashtable, with the colour being the key, and the value being an array of words that will have the colour applied to.