# I would like to color highlight sections of a pipeline string according to a regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, console, format

This is a question of technique, but as an exercise my intention is to write a PS to accept piped input, with a regex as a parameter, and highlight any text matching the regex.

The part I'm not able to find any info on is that it's easy to match text, capturing to a buffer, or to replace text.  But I need to replace matched text with color control, the original text, then resume the previous color.  I can't seem to find any way to generate color output other than with write-output, and can't do separate colors in a single write, which would mean:

-matching the regex

-write-host out all text prior to the match in default color, with -NoNewLine

-write-host the match, with -NoNewLine

-write-host the remainder

This seems messy, and gets even more messy if we want to support multiple matches.
Is there a more eloquent way to do this?

Comment: look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362097/color-words-in-powershell-script-format-table-output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Write-Host` is the right way to do this.  Use the `.Index` and `.Length` properties of the resulting `Match` object to determine where exactly the matched text is.  You just need to be a bit careful keeping track of indices :)

This works for multiple matches, and is not terribly untidy IMO:

```
function ColorMatch
{
   param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
      [string] $InputObject,

      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [string] $Pattern
   )

   begin{ $r = [regex]$Pattern }
   process
   {
       $ms = $r.Matches($inputObject)
       $startIndex = 0

       foreach($m in $ms)
       {
          $nonMatchLength = $m.Index - $startIndex
          Write-Host $inputObject.Substring($startIndex, $nonMatchLength) -NoNew
          Write-Host $m.Value -Back DarkRed -NoNew
          $startIndex = $m.Index + $m.Length
       }

       if($startIndex -lt $inputObject.Length)
       {
          Write-Host $inputObject.Substring($startIndex) -NoNew
       }

       Write-Host
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for this!  I didn't know about index, I appreciate the education.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of latkin's answer. Here I'm extending the Match object such that it can be processed for this purpose - and others - more easily.

```
function Split-Match {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $match
    )
    $sections = @()
    $start = 0
    $text = $m.Line
    foreach ($m in $match.Matches) {
        $i = $m.Index
        $l = $m.Length

        $sections += $false, $text.Substring($start, $i - $start)
        $sections += $true, $text.Substring($i, $l)
        $start = $i + $l
    }
    $sections += $false, $text.Substring($start)
    $match | Add-Member -Force Sections $sections
    $match
}

function Write-Match {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $match
    )
    $fg = "White"
    $bg = "Black"
    foreach($s in $match.Sections) {
        if ($s.GetType() -eq [bool]) {
            if ($s) {
                $fg = "White"
                $bg = "Red"
            } else {
                $fg = "White"
                $bg = "Black"
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $fg -BackgroundColor $bg $s
        }
    }
    Write-Host
}

$string = @'
Match this A
Not this B
Not this C
But this A
'@
$m = $string | select-string -CaseSensitive -AllMatches "A"
$m = Split-Match $m
Write-Match $m
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively I found using [ANSI/VT100 formatting](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/how-to-use-ansi-vt100-formatting-in-powershell-ooh-pretty-colors/) more simple and does exactly what I needed with a much larger range of colors:

```
$esc=[char]27
$fileContents="abc455315testing123455315abc"
$keywordSearch="testing123"

$fileContents -replace $keywordSearch,"$esc[38;2;0;200;255m$keywordSearch$esc[0m"
```

Note this only works in a PowerShell console window not in PowerShell ISE. This [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) also was helpful; specifically this line with regards to choosing a color:

> ESC[ 38;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩ m Select RGB foreground color