# powershell table color results

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a simple array, $Results.  It has two columns:  Task, Result.  I output it to a table as follows:

```
$(foreach($ht in $Results){new-object PSObject -Property $ht}) | Format-Table -AutoSize -Property Task, Result
```

The Result column will contain either "PASS" or "FAIL".  I would like the PASS to be in green and the FAIL to be in red.

Anyone know of a simple way to achieve this?

Ideally only the PASS/FAIL is colorized, but I can live with the entire row being done if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I thought about this one, I noticed something in the related questions on the side that looked similar "Color words in powershell script format-table output".  I took one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368884/3168105) to that question, and hacked it a little, and came up with the following:

```
# Let's Build Some Sample Data To Play With...
$Results = @()
for( $j = 1; $j -le 25; ++$j ) {
    $ans = ( "PASS", "FAIL" ) | Get-Random
    $Results += [PSCustomObject]@{ Task = "Task{0:d2}" -f $j; Result = $ans }
}

# Here's The Important Part...
filter PassFail {
    # Adapted From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368884/3168105
    $Pattern = "PASS|FAIL"

    $split = $_ -split $Pattern
    $found = [regex]::Matches( $_, $Pattern, 'IgnoreCase' )
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $split.Count; ++$i ) {
        Write-Host $split[$i] -NoNewLine
        # Just in case something else pops up...
        switch( $found[$i] ) {
            "Fail" { $Color = "Red" }
            "Pass" { $Color = "Green" }
            default { $Color = "White" }
        }
        Write-Host $found[$i] -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $Color
    }

    Write-Host
}

# And here we put it together...
$Results | Out-String | PassFail
```

This can be adopted to handle more results, it just needs additional lines added to the switch statement, and the additional results added to the `$Pattern` variable.  I won't begin to say this is the best solution (or even a particularly good solution), but it works and seems to behave fairly well.

To use it like you're using it above, with the array of hashtables, you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
$(foreach($ht in $Results){new-object PSObject -Property $ht}) | Format-Table -AutoSize Task, Result | Out-String | PassFail
```

Comment: That works, except that the output tables are off.  The column headings should be "Task" and "Result".  Everything in the left column should be a Task, and everything in the right should be a Result.  So the colors are correct... it's just the placements are now wrong.

Comment: Also want to make sure I say Thanks for the hard work.  It's beyond me -- I have neither the experience with PS or regex.

Comment: I think I see what's happening.  I've updated my answer to include your command with the `PassFail` filter added.  In my tests, it seemed to resolve the left/right order problem.